# Need a formula that moves data in a spreadsheet based on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need a little Excel formula help here. I am trying to figure out how to get the below formula to work.

**=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN() - $A$1)), "")**

I was then given this formula:

**=IF(COLUMN - $A$1 < 1, "", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN() - $A$1)))**

However, the second formula results in a #NAME? error.

Here is what I need the formula to do (see the below image for reference). Row 9 is where sales numbers will appear. Columns C and D are where payment terms are displayed. Row 28 is where collections of payments are calculated.

If payment terms in cell D9 are 5 days, then I need the sales numbers in cells F9:J9 to be displayed to the right (this is basically like a calendar layout) 5 business days (NO WEEKENDS, the grayed out spaces, so 7 actual days) in the collections section below (row 28). For instance, if there were $1,900 in sales on Thursday, Jan 7 (cell I9) and payment terms are 5 days (cell D9), then I need that amount displayed in cell P28 on Thursday, Jan 14.Does that make sense?

Let me know if you need any additional info to solve this problem. Thanks!

[UPDATED SPREADHSEET IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vpqq.png)

Comment: what happens if `COLUMN - $A$1 < 1` is changed to `COLUMN() - $A$1 < 1` ?

Comment: Doing that fixes the #NAME? error, but there ate still issues with this formula. First, it fetches data labels to the left of the data table that are not part of the data set. I do not want these labels included in the collections section, just the sales data.

Comment: at which cell does the above formula is applied? | `to the left of the data table ` <-- which one is the data table in the screenshot?

Comment: I have included a new image above, please see the edit. The formula should be applied in the cell range E28:X32. It should serve to display sales data above in the cell range E9:X13, offset to the right (like a calendar) by the number of days in cell range C9:C13. Does this answer your question?

Comment: The formula above is in cell E28.

Comment: `figure out how to get the below formula to work` > try out the example in excel documentation for each formula used. | btw.. please share if the solution works/not/understandable.. ( :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX($E9:$X9,MATCH(WORKDAY(E$4,-$C9),$E$5:$X$5,0)),0)=0,"",IFERROR(INDEX($E9:$X9,MATCH(WORKDAY(E$4,-$C9),$E$5:$X$5,0)),0))
```

should do.

The key formula however, is just :

```
INDEX($E9:$X9,MATCH(WORKDAY(E$4,-$C9),$E$5:$X$5,0))
```

Idea : use [index match](https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact) approach with the date `workday()` shifted. if needed, `workday.intl()` is applicable too.

Comment: Thank you, but this formula is not quite working. No data is being carried over, just blank cells. Do you know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: my bad.. i had misread the row 5 as row 4 .. | corrected. pls have a try. /(^_^)

Comment: if the solution work. please click on the 'tick' (to mark that this question was 'answered' in the system)

Comment: This suggestion did not work, so I had to repost the question. However, the circumstances are different in my new question, it is a different problem to solve.

Comment: if this duplicate question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68380975/need-to-revise-this-formula-that-displays-data-based-on-another-cells-contents) had already answered ur concern.. please detele this question instead.

Comment: u don't need to report the question.. u just have to highlight in the comment that this solution doesn't work.. others will notice (pray for it).. and (hopefully..) try their alternative solution to  the question.. and post another alternative answer. u r not sharing whether the solution is working or not.. so others will (normally) assume the quest to resolve the mistery is over.. "-_-