# Need to revise this formula that displays data based on another cell's contents

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I can't get this formula working properly. Here is what I need to do (see included image below):

I need the data in rows 9-10 (sales) to be displayed/copied in rows 28-29 (collections) based on the number in cells C9 and C10 (payment terms). For example, if there are $1,900 in GM sales on Tuesday, Jan 5 (cell F9) and payment terms are 10 days (cell C9), then I need $1,900 displayed on Tuesday, Jan 19 (cell P28), in the collections section (rows 28-29), 10 business days from when the sales were made. Does this make sense? Here is the formula I am using now (starting in cell E28 and being dragged to the right):

**=IF(COLUMN() - E9 < 1, 0, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9, COLUMN() - $C$9)))**

However, it is not working completely. It is moving the data labels to the left of the data table that are not supposed to be included in the  data table. Only sales data starting in cell E9 are supposed to be moved. You can see this issue in row 28 (columns J-N) in the image below.

This formula also has to work with payment terms from 1 day - 10 days. So, the $5,000 in Ford sales on Monday, Jan 4 (cell F10), with payment terms of 3 days (cell C10), needs to be displayed on Friday, Jan 8 (cell I29).

Let me know if you need any additional details to solve this issue. Thanks!

[image: Current Formula is Not Working]

Comment: "So, the $5,000 in Ford sales on Monday, Jan 4 (cell F10), with payment terms of 3 days (cell C10), needs to be displayed on Friday, Jan 8 (cell I29)." I don't see why Jan 4 + 3 business days = Jan 8 (4 business days). Also what's the use of the average terms in direct cashflow?

Comment: If the only logic is to shift the results of the amounts the number of average terms days to the right, then look into INDEX instead of INDIRECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
`=IFERROR(INDEX($E$9:$X$13,MATCH($B28,$B$9:$B$13,0),MATCH(WORKDAY(E$5,-INDEX($C$9:$C$13,MATCH($B28,$B$9:$B$13,0))),$E$5:$X$5,0)),0)`

The formula indexes the sales amounts and shows the amount in the row where the customer name mentioned at sales equals the customer at the result section with the column where the result date equals the date mentioned at sales minus the number of workdays mentioned behind the customer name at the sales section.

Comment: Thank you, this formula is almost working. It seems that the formula is not taking into consideration that weekends are invalid. Collections can only take place in the cells that are visible, weekdays. With this formula, when I use payment terms of 7 days, it moves all the sales data to the next week and works fine. However, when I use payment terms of 5 days, only three sales numbers appear in cells J28-L28, the rest being lost to the weekend. How can this be fixed?

Comment: The edited formula works perfectly! You're a genius. Thank you so much. Are there any recommendations you have for me on how I could simplify my method here or do you think it's alright the way it is?

Comment: That depends on what you (or the ones you report to) want to do with it.

Comment: I have an additional question if you don't mind. I just realized that I haven't taken bank holidays into account. There are certain days (which I already know and have a list of) on which collections cannot fall because banks are closed. How would I be able to avoid/ignore these cells?

Comment: Why not calculate the date of the expected payment instead of showing the money under the date and calculate back. So instead of where you now have the calculation use this `=WORKDAY(E$5,INDEX($C$9:$C$13,MATCH($B30,$A$9:$B$13,0)),$Z:$Z)` and it shows the workday of expected payment instead of an amount. (In this example column Z holds the holidays)

Comment: I actually thought of using the workday formula for this, and may still be able to, but what we need is to show the amounts that we will be paid on certain days, not the days on which we will be paid. I was just wondering if it was possible to "gray out" certain dates, ignore them, have the formula skip over them somehow or some kind of workaround. I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Comment: The amount in the sales section is the amount. The date will show when it's expected to arrive.

Comment: since the `bank holidays` is not mentioned in the question.. I think this solution had already fully resolve the question.. right?

Comment: @P.b would u mind sharing the details/logic behind the solution so it can assist the OP to [troubleshoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410778/how-to-fix-this-formula-so-bank-holidays-are-skipped-over) it ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what you are asking me to do here. I just need to find a way to get my question answered. How do I do this?

Comment: @greene I added a textual explanation of what the formula calculates. I hope my explanation makes it understandable.